# javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${{"cat", "dog", "giraffe"}}]

Tags: jsp, collections, el

What version of EL are sets and lists supported?  I'm trying to define a set of data in Java Expression Language

```
${{"cat", "dog", "giraffe"}}
```

I get the following exception:

```
javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${{"cat", "dog", "giraffe"}]
    org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:146)
    org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:172)
    org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:217)
    org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:67)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1025)
    org.apache.jsp.user_jsp._jspService(user_jsp.java:78)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Answer (score 1):

Expression Language 3.0 supports lists, sets, and maps.  Tomcat 7.0 only supports EL 2.2.  This is why my script is not working.

Comment: brackets [] are used for lists, braces {} are used for sets.

Answer (score 0):

Which container are you using? Here is demonstration code that works in my Tomcat 8.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="animalList" value='${["cat","dog","giraffe"]}'/>
<html>
    <body>
            <c:forEach items="${animalList}" var="animal">
                ${animal}
            </c:forEach>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using tomcat 7.0